# How WSO2 API manager implements microservices service discovery and service registry feature

Tags: wso2, microservices, service-discovery

How WSO2 API manager implements microservices service discovery and service 
registry feature

Answer (score 0):

In API manager 3.0.0 release you can discover micro-services deployed in kubernetes.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Discovering+Service+Endpoints

Comment: When this 3.0.0 version is going to be released.

Comment: It is planned to release on December 2018. You can try the latest milestone release at https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.0.0-m27.